# how to populate enum value in mysql with laravel 4.1

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, laravel

I'm new to Laravel, but now I want to populate the value that I set as `enum` in MySQL database to a select box using Laravel 4 for my Schema like below

```
$table->enum('user_type', array('premium','free','agent free','agent premium'));
```

Comment: I don't think there's a way to automatically do this without doing SHOW TABLE kinda stuff. Your best bet it to store this as a class constant or static/instance array, then refer to that when you do the dropdown, like: `Form::select('user_type', User::$user_types)` kinda thing

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://laravel.com/docs/html#drop-down-lists) is the reference on the doc.

```
{{ Form::select('user_type',
                array( 'premium' => 'premium', 'free' => 'free','agent free' => 'agent free', 'agent premium' => 'agent premium'),
                $user->user_type) }}
```